# Jar file MANIFEST with Class-Path to Maven artefacts

Tags: maven, jar, manifest

Probably I'm missing something very basic, I have a JAR file (**Util**) the artefact of my project, which will be used as a util lib in various of my projects. The **Util** has a list of runtime dependencies. I don't want to create a fat jar to assembly all dependencies there, instead I want to include all **Util** dependencies in the MANIFEST file in the way the MAVEN will be able to download them automatically if **Util** will be included in a project, also I don't want to bother a **Util** consumer be aware of these dependencies.

I want to instruct MAVEN to download **Util** dependencies automatically. My guess was to leverage somehow Jar manifest *Class-Path:* attribute to enable this but can't make it working. Tried to google it a lot without success, now I'm not sure if my guess was right. Any ideas how it could be implemented.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand you, that's exactly what I am looking for for quite some time. I thought about writing a Maven plugin, but gave up after having a closer look a Mavens source code. If this is for some local environment only, you can put an absolute path to your repo in the classpath (dependency plugin) and ensure manually (go-offline) that everything is available locally. A symlink can possibly avoid the absolute path.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit surprised, I thought what I'm looking for is the existing OOTB maven  feature. Regarding you suggestion of using an absolute path, it won't work for me since the jar might be used from any environment. I was sure that I saw libraries which instruct maven to download their dependencies along with the lib itself. Now writing this lines, I thought it could be in a pom.xml file and has nothing with JAR file. Any case having the same feature for JAR file could be a nice capability as well

Comment: So probably I didn't understand you.